# Laravel Artisan Routes command throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just ran "usr/local/bin/php artisan routes"

And got this back:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Argument 1 passed to 
 Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::findPatternFilters() must be an instance of  
Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request, string given, called in 
\/Users\/myaccount\/Code\/scratch\/dice\/laravel\/vendor\/laravel
\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/RoutesCommand.php on line 170 and 
defined","file":"\/Users\/jmorati\/Code\/scratch\/dice\/laravel\/bootstrap\/compiled.php",
"line":4838}}
```

I can't find anyone else having this issue, so I am hoping someone can clue me in on what is happening there.

I have removed all routes and tried it again and tried it with the default get route all with the same error each time.

Any advice on what is causing this error would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you have in your `routes.php` and `filters.php`?

Comment: I removed any special routes I made and just left the original get route and get the same error, but I didn't think of the filters. I have also completely emptied the routes file and get a message that there are no routes. Do you think it's a malformed route doing it?

Comment: I think you should probably show us your `routes.php` and `filters.php` files. That's the only way we'll know.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with either a route or a filter.. Also, did you download Laravel recently?

Comment: It turns out that there was an issue with an update. Ran everything again and composer routes works as expected. Thanks for your time.